# How to combine AddOpenIdConnect() and AddIdentityServerAuthentication() in one resource server?

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

Can somebody help me with my current configuration for protecting our server using Identity Server 4, currently I'm using package IdentityServer4 2.3.0. I found that when I hit one of my api with a valid token, it always return 401 Unauthorized or 302 Found. My comment on listing below show my problem:

```
services
   .AddAuthentication()
   .AddOpenIdConnect(
      "oidc",
      "OpenID Connect",
      x =>
      {
         x.Authority = "https://localhost:44378"; // Try to set breakpoint here, it hitted.
         x.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

         x.ClientId = "myclient;
         x.SaveTokens = true;
         x.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

         x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
         {
            NameClaimType = "name",
            RoleClaimType = "role"
         };
      })
   .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(
      "Bearer",
      x =>
      {
         x.Authority = "https://localhost:44378"; // Try to set breakpoint here, not hitted.
         x.ApiName = "api1";
         x.ApiSecret = "apisecret";
         x.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
      })
   ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how I do it to get the Hybrid flow working:

```
        services
            .AddAuthentication(
                (options) =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                })
            .AddCookie(
                (options) =>
                {
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/home/accessdenied");
                })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(
                "oidc",
                (options) =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.Authority = applicationConfiguration.IdentityServerBaseUri;
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.ClientId = "<id>";
                    options.ClientSecret = "<secret>";
                    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                    options.Scope.Add("lithium-datalookup-vatnumber");
                    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                    options.Scope.Add("profile");
                    options.Scope.Add("email");
                    options.Scope.Add("subscription");
                });
```

Comment: Thanks Sir for your answer. But with your code, are my api controllers will be protected by "Bearer" authorization? Please advise.

Comment: Yes, give it a try. :)

Comment: Sorry for late comment. I accepted this as right answer coz it works. Thanks anyway.